# Ajax Load More button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to make my Load more button disappear if there are no more posts available in my response.

This is the the only solution that I could've think. The problem is that the button disappears after I click one more the button.

```
.done(function(response) {
  if (response == "") {
    $loadMore.slideUp();
  };
});
```

Ex: I have 7 posts in my query and I show 3 per page. I press Load more one and now I have 6. I press again I have 7. (Now I want the button to disappear). But I have to press again to make it disappear.

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead -

```
.done(function(response) {
  if (response == "") {
    $loadMore.hide();
   };
 });
```

Comment: No ... I didn't make myself clear. Sorry. The problem is that I have to check if there are more posts to load. If not don't show the button. The problem is it is showing ... and after I click Load More again it is checking if response == ""

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
.done(function(response) {
  if (response.length < 3) {
    $loadMore.slideUp();
   };
 });
```

If your function returns only 1 or 2 results, the "response" still won't be empty or null.
The important question is: how many items are in the response variable. Because if it's less than 3, there won't be more posts, what means the load more btw can be hidden.